# Social media icons change to respective color upon hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to achieve an effect I've seen on multiple sites. The social media icons once hovered over; each switch from gray-scale to their respective color. For example; the Facebook icon once hovered over changes to a Facebook blue. How do I achieve this effect by using jQuery, HTML, and CSS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fontawesome.css`

like

```
<span class="fa fa-facebook" style="color:blue"></span>
```

Now if you want to change color on hover, then something goes like this:

```css
    .fa-facebook-square:hover {
        color: #3b5998;
        -o-transition:.5s;
        -ms-transition:.5s;
        -moz-transition:.5s;
        -webkit-transition:.5s;
        transition:.5s;
    }

   .fa-facebook-square{
        -o-transition:.5s;
        -ms-transition:.5s;
        -moz-transition:.5s;
        -webkit-transition:.5s;
        transition:.5s;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i>
```

You can also use other social icons with their respective colors. Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS3 filters and then remove the effect on hover.

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
  transition: all 2s;
}

img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/facebook-announces-clickable-hashtags--resolution-media-17.png">
```